# Do we need to test the return value of bind_param when building prepared statements in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

Linked question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66943701/why-is-my-url-parameter-value-not-being-added-correctly-to-the-sql-database).

I have upgraded the code in the linked question to use a prepared statement.

I now have:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `workbook-data` (`workbook-language`, `gui-language`, `foreign-language-group-mode`, `version`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssis', $mwblang, $guilang, $flgmode, $version);

$mwblang = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['mwblang']);
$guilang = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['guilang']);
$flgmode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['flg']);
$version = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['version'] ?? '210061');

if ($stmt->execute()) {
  echo "<br>" . "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " .  mysqli_error($conn);
}

$stmt->close();
```

According to the documentation for [`bind_param`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) it states this about the return value:

> Returns true on success or false on failure.

In these official examples they don't seem to do any error checking for failure. Should be we testing the return value? I have done so for `execute()` but I am not sure how much checking is needed.

Comment: Btw.: You shouldn't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` anymore, the prepared statements work without them.

Comment: FYI: *don't* `mysqli_real_escape_string` if you’re using parametrized statements. It’s redundant and only messes up your data.

Comment: @Progman So just use, eg: `$mwblang = $_GET['mwblang'];`

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You might not need to check for errors manually when you let exceptions throw instead (and catch them of course), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be checking for the return value of any of mysqli functions. This is just pointless. When you [enable proper mysqli error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439) you will be automatically informed of all the errors.

If you decide to keep the error reporting silenced for some strange reason, then **you must check every single mysqli function call** including `bind_param()`. If you do check for the return value, make sure to never display the error message on the screen. Log the errors to a file in a safe place.

So, your code should look like this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'test');
$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

// ...

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `workbook-data` (`workbook-language`, `gui-language`, `foreign-language-group-mode`, `version`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ssis', $mwblang, $guilang, $flgmode, $version);
$stmt->execute();
```

or like this:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'test');
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    error_log($conn->connect_error);
}
if (false === $conn->set_charset('utf8mb4')) {
    error_log($conn->error);
}

// ...

if (false === ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `workbook-data` (`workbook-language`, `gui-language`, `foreign-language-group-mode`, `version`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"))) {
    error_log($conn->error);
}
if (false === $stmt->bind_param('ssis', $mwblang, $guilang, $flgmode, $version)) {
    error_log($stmt->error);
}
if (false === $stmt->execute()) {
    error_log($stmt->error);
}
```

Note how there are 3 different ways of reading the error message depending on which function you called. Manual error checking is much more verbose.